# Session Variables, Cookies and UpdatePanel Load event

Tags: asp.net, cookies, updatepanel

I have a question: in my project I have a LinkButton which does the following:

```
Response.Cookies("synthetic_fm_user_session")("session_id") = String_Session_Id
Response.Cookies("synthetic_fm_user_session").Expires = DateTime_Session_Stop

Session("Integer_User_Id") = Integer_User_Id

UpdatePanel.Update()
```

My UpdatePanel Load event looks like that:

```
If Not Request.Cookies("synthetic_fm_user_session") Is Nothing Then

    Panel1.Visible = True

End If

If Not Session("Integer_User_Id") Is Nothing Then

    Panel2.Visible = True

End If
```

Then, when I click this LinkButton which sets both Session Variables and Cookies to some value (Not Nothing) and updates UpdatePanel in UpdatePanel Load event both Session Variables and Cookies are still Nothing! And on the second UpdatePanel.Update() Session Variables and Cookies become Not Nothing!

Why does it happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you made sure the values being written are not Nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UpdatePanel's Load event is only executed when the Page is loaded. Running UpdatePanel.Update() will not execute the load event again.

Looks like you should have a separate function to set the update panels visibility and execute that rather than UpdatePanel.Update in the Page Load event

Comment: But in my project I have to execute some functions on every UpdatePanel.Update(). Is it possible? Which event should I use?

Comment: Create your own "event" that will execute all your code and then the last thing you call the UpdatePanel.Update() in that function. You use this new function rather than UpdatePanel.Update() directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll try to do it this way!